# SFP Card compatibility

Tags: centos, network-attached-storage, drivers, pci-express, sfp

We are installing our first "professional" server configuration in the office. We will install a HP ProLiant DL120 Gen9 that will provide a hypervisor based on CentOS / KVM and should be connected to a Synology RS818+ via iSCSI to access the virtual disks (including host's boot drive).

Since the DL120 Gen9 only offers two 1 Gbit Ethernet ports, we are evaluating how we can increase the network throughput to the NAS. At the moment we are favouring hooking both, NAS and Server, via SFP+ / Twinax via the Switch to the network instead of the onboard RJ-45 Ports.

We did not find sufficient information on the web on how picky hardware an OS are about card compatibility. Especially HP only lists a few modern HP PCIe 3 cards as compatible. From my point of view PCIe 3 is a standard and there should not be any concern about installing other vendor's cards, as long as there is a driver available for CentOS. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: You're right, any PCIe card, especially from a big manufacturer, will work - the thing with buying through HPE is that their firmware bundle will update the code on every part of their servers, you'd have to manage a different one separately. Also the card would also be covered by their server support contract if bought through them but not if bought elsewhere.